# Windows: Determine number of cores from a performance monitor file?

Tags: windows, performance, performance-monitoring, performance-counters

Is there any way to determine how many cores a particular machine's CPU has based on a Performance Monitor file I have?

Additionally, can we see if hyperthreading is enabled?

For a period of high usage, it seems the total % Processor Time is 94 which would suggest 1 core at nearly 100% usage - I believe, it would be  >100 for 2 cores etc?

Additionally, the % Process time is 196% which would suggests hyperthreading is enabled?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'ProcessorPerformance' will show a number of instances, usually called 'PPM_Processor_X' - that's the number of logical cores available to you. No way to tell if they're regular or HT threads though sorry.

Comment: Where can I find that, @Chopper3?

Comment: it's one of the perfmon root counters